# Magnetization force on domains after alignment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

When a domain is aligned to an exterior uniform magnetic field.
There are no forces acting on it? 
Magnetization force = 0, and all other force?

Comment: Do you know what a dipole is? If you know what it is, then you will have a slightly easier time understanding this.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus restated question, I wrote it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your magnetic field is very very strong, usually your domain is not perfectly aligned due to the dipole-dipole interaction.
But if you assume a perfect aligned domain, there should be no torque acting on the domain.
Usually, you talk about torque instead of force exerted on a magnetic dipole. Only when the external magnetic field is nonuniform, the magnetic dipole will feel a net force proportional to the gradient of the field.

Comment: So magnetization force is a torque applied on domains to flip them correct?

Comment: Roughly there. But you should distinguish a force from a torque. A force induces a change in the linear momentum, while a torque causes a change in the angular momentum. In this case, magnetic moment is related to angular momentum.